# Is `std::istream_iterator<float>` reading out-of-range number undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

```
const std::string str = "-5.73945e-39";
std::istringstream iss(str);
auto vals = std::vector<float>(std::istream_iterator<float>(iss), std::istream_iterator<float>{});
```

If I compile with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.16.10) on my M1 chip Mac, size of `vals` is 0, but if I compile with other compilers (using any c++ online playground), the size of `vals` is 1.

Apparently the value is out of `float` range. Anyone knows whether this is leading to undefined behavior? Thanks!

Local and online c++ playground compiling and running.

Comment: its a vector, how it have a value of `0` ? Do you mean its first element? The size?

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get a compiler error.  Try changing `std::istream_iterator<float>` to `std::istream_iterator<float>{}`.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: How can an `std::istream_iterator<float>` object be "reading out of bounds"? Out of bounds of what? The stream? Perhaps you mean "out of **range**"?

Comment: works as expected with clang after fixing the typo here https://godbolt.org/z/c5vcW3a1E

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt simply says "Extracts an extended floating-point value potentially skipping preceding whitespace. The value is stored to a given reference value." I wonder if this is specified better in the actual spec.

Comment: sorry missed `{}` in my last line of code...

Comment: @MooingDuck it says more than that: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get

Comment: check value of `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()`.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as an out of range value for small numbers. If its not representable it just gets truncated to +/-0: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8TMrd1cTa looks like `-5.73945e-39` is [subnormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number) value. Not sure how `float` works on on M1/2 chips.

Comment: To expand on 463035818_is_not_a_number's comment: in the end [`std::strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) will take care of parsing the number with some intermediate steps possibly modifying the string passed.

Comment: does look like libc++ has different behaviour here: https://godbolt.org/z/d79ev7Y5f

Comment: when the value is out of range extraction fails. Because extraction can always fail for various reasons the better quesiton is how to detect the fail, and unfortunately I have no clue ;) https://godbolt.org/z/3cKe6Mq81

Comment: fwiw, no this is not undefined behavior

Comment: The vector and istream_iterator is irrelevant to the problem at hand.  `float f; if (iss >> f) std::cout << "success\n"; else std::cout << "failure\n";`

Comment: @Eljay but how do you dectect success or failure when the iterator is used? The state of the stream is the same, whether extraction fails or not. Or I am missing something silly.... https://godbolt.org/z/qczPd6xfs

Comment: After the operation, you do `if (iss) std::cout << "success\n"; else std::cout << "failure\n";`

Comment: @Eljay but after using the iterator has been used `iss == false` either because of `eof` or because extraction failed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number • oh drat.  Well, perhaps the stream could set the `throw` bit on error via `.exceptions` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not undefined behavior.  If the extraction operation on the stream fails, the failbit should be set, which can be examined by calling `iss.fail()`.  When this failure occurs, it will also cause the iterator to become equal to the end iterator, stopping the extraction.

So, if there is a parse issue, the iteration will stop before the first invalid value, and you can check this by examining the failbit.

```
if (iss.fail() ) {
  std::cout << "Error occurred\n";
} else {
  // Successful path
}
```

For a more comprehensive list of what each of the state bits mean, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate